# Are integer numbers generated with AutoFixture 3 unique?

Tags: c#, autofixture

Are integer numbers generated with `IFixture.Create<int>()` unique?

[The Wiki says](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Version-History#random-numbers) that numbers are random, but it also tells us this

> The first numbers are generated within the range of [1, 255], as this
>   is a set of values that are valid for all numeric data types. The
>   smallest numeric data type in .NET is System.Byte, which fits in this
>   range.
>
> When the first 255 integers have been used, numbers are subsequently
>   picked from the range [256, 32767], which corresponds to the remaining
>   positive numbers available for System.Int16.

Two related things at GitHub:

https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/2

https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/pull/7

And what about those unit tests?

https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixtureUnitTest/GeneratorTest.cs#L33

```
[Theory, ClassData(typeof(CountTestCases))]
public void StronglyTypedEnumerationYieldsUniqueValues(int count)
{
    // Fixture setup
    var sut = new Generator<T>(new Fixture());
    // Exercise system
    var actual = sut.Take(count);
    // Verify outcome
    Assert.Equal(count, actual.Distinct().Count());
    // Teardown
}
```

https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixtureUnitTest/GeneratorTest.cs#L57

```
[Theory, ClassData(typeof(CountTestCases))]
public void WeaklyTypedEnumerationYieldsUniqueValues(int count)
{
    // Fixture setup
    IEnumerable sut = new Generator<T>(new Fixture());
    // Exercise system
    var actual = sut.OfType<T>().Take(count);
    // Verify outcome
    Assert.Equal(count, actual.Distinct().Count());
    // Teardown
}
```

I have not found a statement that says the generated numbers are unique, only those bits of information that would suggest it, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently, AutoFixture endeavours to create unique numbers, but **it doesn't guarantee it**. For instance, you can exhaust the range, which is most likely to happen for `byte` values. If, for instance, you request 300 `byte` values, you *will* get duplicates, because there's only 256 values to choose from.

AutoFixture will happily reuse values once the initial set has been depleted; the alternative would be to throw an exception.

If it's important for a test case that numbers are unique, I would recommend **making this explicit** in the test case itself. You can combine `Generator<T>`  with `Distinct` for this:

```
var uniqueIntegers = new Generator<int>(new Fixture()).Distinct().Take(10);
```

If you're using [AutoFixture.Xunit2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit2), you can request a `Generator<T>` via a test method argument:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void MyTest(Generator<int> g, string foo)
{
    var uniqueIntegers = g.Distinct().Take(10);
    // more test code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The first numbers are generated within the range of [1, 255] and there are [no duplicates present](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/407#issuecomment-109316269). Above that range, it *is* currently possible to get duplicates.

[This](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/407) issue contains useful information on how the built-in algorithm can be improved.